# Some details on basic Javascript on Express.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, backend

This is probably basic JS stuff but please what is the difference between

```
app.get("/api/products/1", (req, res) => {
  const singleProduct = products.find((product) => {
    product.id === 1;
  });
  res.json(singleProduct);
});
```

---

**AND**

---

```
app.get("/api/products/1", (req, res) => {
  const singleProduct = products.find((product) => product.id === 1);
  res.json(singleProduct);
});
```

They look the same to me, the former is me trying to code ahead of the instructor and I was not getting any JSON response on the browser, while the latter is the instructor's code which he got the JSON response

Comment: The second has an implicit return, the first does not. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#description

Comment: `products.find((product) => {product.id === 1;});` always returns `undefined`.

Comment: The first one (currently incorrect example), to be properly formatted should use a `return product.id === 1;` - and it will be equal to the second (valid) example which uses implicit return.

Comment: The first code returns undefined and the second code returns true or false depending on weather `product.id` equals `1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first code will always returns `undefined`. Because it's missing a `return` inside the function. You should know that when a function doesn't have `return` keyword it's by default returning `undefined`. And if you using curly braces in function, you have to explicitly specify the `return` keyword if you want to return a value.

```
  const singleProduct = products.find((product) => {
    return product.id === 1;
  });
```

The second code works because when you don't use *curly braces* JS implicitly returns the result of the comparison `product.id === 1`.